# How do characters store values when being compared to each other in an if else?

Tags: c

I'm creating a loop that basically has a (y/n) yes, no answer and I wanted to use an if else inside of a do while loop. When using the `input == Y` it seems to not accept it, so I'm wondering that's even possible in C? Or if I'm approaching in the wrong way.

I tried just a simple if input == Y but that didn't work, then I tried a `strcmp` and that didn't seem to work either. I'm at the `strcmp` part because I think I might be close to the answer with that but I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding what's going on with the char values.

```
printf("Would you like to print another invoice? Y=yes, N=No\n");
do {
    scanf("%s", &newInvoice);
    if(strcmp(newInvoice, Y)!= 0) {
        main();
    }
    else if(strcmp(newInvoice, N)!= 0) {
        printf("Goodbye!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid Entry (it has to be y or n):\n");
    }
} while(strcmp(newInvoice, N)!= 0);
```

When I had just `input == Y` it wanted me to initialize Ym and N so that didn't seem to be the answer. I would like the loop to repeat the question and input until they say yes or no; if they enter something like G or whatever other character it needs to loop again.

Comment: Where you do assign a value to `N` and `Y`?

Comment: Note: you should not call `main()`

Comment: you probably mean to compare newInvoice to the characters 'Y' and 'N' instead of the variables Y and N, in which case `if(newInvoice == 'Y')` should do the job.

Comment: Calling `main` recursively is legal in C, but illegal in C++.  (It is never a ***good*** idea, however)

Comment: @josemz the OP would have to compare `if (*newInvoice == 'Y') since s/he'd only want to look at the first character on the input

Comment: @bruceg I thought `newInvoice` was a character but now that I see the `%s` in `scanf` you're probably right. Guess we can't know for sure if we don't see the declaration of `newInvoice`.

Comment: char newInvoice[1], Y, N; sorry this is it

Comment: The recursive call to `main()` is probably _not_ a good idea.  You should be looping, not recursing.  Also, since you've not shown how any of the variables are defined (nor how most of them are initialized), it is hard to be sure of anything.  You should check that the `scanf()` returns `1`; if not, you've got an EOF or other error condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the following (changed abelenky's code a little). The below makes sure the lower case letters get accepted, but it's probably a little clunky, and may be represented a little more elegant.

```
int main()
{
    char newInvoice, buffer;
    do 
    {
        newInvoice = getchar();
        bufferClean(&buffer); //see underneath the code for the explanation.
        if (newInvoice == 'Y' || newInvoice == 'y') 
        {
            printf("you've chosen YES, continue ......\n");
            break; // breaks the loop and continues with the code.
        }
        else if (newInvoice == 'N' || newInvoice == 'n') 
        {
            printf("you've chosen NO, Goodbye!\n");
            return 1; //main returns 1 and ends the program
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Invalid Entry (it has to be y or n):\n");
        }
    } while(1);

    printf("exited the loop\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, asking for users' input is a little tricky. I suggest clearing the buffer after using it, as it passes on the `newline char` and may skip any further input prompt.
I  have created a little function to do so:

```
void bufferClean(char *buff)
{
    while ((*buff = getchar()) != '\n' && *buff != EOF);
}
```

Just declare a `char buffer` in `main()` with no value, and pass it on to the function every time you want to clear the buffer (I do every time after asking for users' input). I'm a novice, and if I'm making any mistakes please point them out!

Comment: You'd better hope the user never enters more than one character.

Comment: it actually loops and saves one char only according to the debugger, then overwrites  the old one, unless it actually accesses the further memory and doesn't show up in debugger (leading to undefined behavior)? But yeah, I did suggest to use getchar();. I personally wouldn't play around with one element array, it's just for the purpose of this example, as the author used a string.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the debugger. `scanf` will read an unlimited number of characters up until the first whitespace. Since your array is only one char long that's going to trash the stack and produce UB if the user types in more than one char. I know it's only an example, but you shouldn't teach bad habits. There are multiple ways to solve this problem that don't trash the stack.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Carey. Please have a look at the edited code above. Tested and works just fine with any input, and hopefully doesn't mess with the stack anymore!

Comment: Much better solution.